# Buying plane tickets offline in Nepal

Tags: air-travel, canada, tickets, nepal

Is it possible to buy air tickets from Kathmandu, Nepal to Toronto, Canada from a Nepali travel agent or any airline operating from Nepal? I need to buy tickets "off-line" because my credit limit does not allow me to buy the tickets on-line.

Asking the bank to increase my credit limit is an option indeed, but I don't have sufficient time for that. I'll be taking of soon.

Comment: This seems a bit too localized.  There are multiple airlines operating in both Toronto Pearson and Kathmandu and you can get tickets directly from them directly.

Comment: @Karlson - localised? He's merely asking if there are travel agents (not on the internet) in Nepal.  I think it's a valid question, just needs the title changed. Raiyan - I'm changing the title to be a bit clearer, let me know if that's ok.

Comment: A little research on the internet shows it's no big deal after all, but still I would like to have the question the way it is. Someone else might find it useful in future.

Comment: @MarkMayo - sure, no probs.

Comment: Most airlines have ticket desks at the airport, worst case you could just head over there and buy tickets direct from who you want to fly with

Comment: Most (all?) credit cards allow you to put the account into credit, which in effect allows you to increase the credit limit available.  eg, if your limit is $500 and the tickets are $800, then deposit/transfer $300 or more into your credit card (giving it a +$300 balance) and you will then be able to spend the $800.

Comment: @Doc, I nearly suggested this, but neither of my UK ones allowed this.  My NZ one works just fine though.

Comment: @Doc This is indeed true, however the processing time between transfering the money to your credit card and it actually resulting in an increased limit can take some time. This does not work in case you need to travel soon. Although the OP doesn't indicate he needs to travel soon

Comment: @Andra thanks for pointing that out. Actually, I'm traveling very soon. Edited the question.

Answer (score 4):

A quick [search](https://www.google.ca/search?q=travel%20agent%20flights%20kathmandu&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb) shows that a few people have found travel agencies in Kathmandu.

For example, there's [Kailash International Travels and Tours](http://kailashitnltt.com/).  Their contact phone is +977-1-4414696, 4425456 if you want to see if they can help you, before you go down to their offices.

Comment: Kailash haven't replied to my email yet. Looking for other travel agents in Kathmandu area now.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you can,

the main base of tourism business of Nepal is offline network, You can see lots of Travel and Tour Agencies, specially in Thamel area. You can ask them.

My suggestion is, try on multiple agencies before buy so you can be sure for best price.

Answer (score 0):

Every major airline that operates flights to and from Nepal has its offices or GSA there. Google for the choice of your airline and call the local office.

Answer (score 0):

There are travel agencies in pretty much every *chowk* (suburb) in every major city of Nepal. Most people in Nepal dont have international credit cards and the whole internet banking and shopping scene isn't as developed. So I would say it would actually be easier to buy tickets offline in Nepal. Just make sure you compare the prices with different travel agencies before buying.